# I don't know how to use the / and /home later. Like where should I download stuff in ubuntu. I want to know clearly about this stuff. Can anyone

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, root

My doubt is if I do it like root in ssd and home in hdd, where should I put my downloaded files in root or home?
256 gb ssd
1 tb hdd
best way to install ubuntu

Comment: ubuntu by default will install to the ssd. Where you have a choice of where to save programs to such as pdf's and other downloads like ebooks etc, you could elect to save them to the 1TB hdd, provided you have mounted the drive (perhaps in fstab) at boot time to make things more transparent. Your 256 gb ssd is more than adequate to contain system files and downloaded apps (such as those downloaded by default - firefox, LibreOffice etc). A good example would be to save LO files like Calc in an appropriately named directory on the 1TB hdd.

Comment: You've not provide very specific details.   If i use `wget` to download files and don't specify a save location, they'll go into $PWD or the present working directory.  If you download them using a GUI tool such as browser (you didn't say if you're talking about a desktop or server install) they go wherever the browser is setup to save them, which usually is `$HOME/Downloads` (ie. `/home/$USER/Downloads/` where $USER is your userid).   ie. it depends how you download & what you use to download...

Comment: Read `man hier`. It describes what directories are used for what.

Comment: You can always refer the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) when looking for information about what every directory should do on Linux. The general rule of thumb here is that permanent user data goes into `/home/<user>` and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `/` at all. That folder contains system files. Only system administrators may have business there.

You maintain your user files in your home folder, which is a folder named after your login name under `/home`. For example, if your login is `eternalsouls`, then your home folder will be `/home/eternalsouls`. In a default Ubuntu install, a "Downloads" folder is set up where you can organize your downloaded files.

External USB drives are automatically mounted when you plug in on a folder under `/media/<yourlogin>`. You can organize the files on a plugged in volume as you see fit.

Also any other volume set up by the administrator for data storage, and where the user is granted permission to read/write, can be used and organized as the user sees fit.

In Linux, it is in principle only the administrator who is concerned with partitions. Once mounted, partitions seamlessly are integrated into a file system. The user is only concerned with the file system. In your case, `/home` is mounted on a HDD. That is where all your user files will go by default.

Comment: So the one which is partitioned in SSD isn't something I need to worry about? I have 256 gb SSD but my windows let me use the free space over a limit. How much should I use from 256gb SSD and 1Tb hdd. Ram is 16gb

Comment: can You give more precise one on one personal clarifications for my doubts?

Comment: You decide on how to use and organize files on your drive. The administrator (root) decides where you are allowed to place files.